# How do I get cell number and sheet name of excel by office.js Office.initialize?

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, react-router, office-js

[image]
Sometime getting the attached image error
Getting the below error while running the application in excel add-in.

**Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.**

I have used the Office.initialize function to get the cell Number and sheet number where we click on Excel. But it is not executed, if we will reload that page after that it will run (Office.initialize).

If we render that page by "a" tag (a href) it will run fine but with props.history.push it will not run.

```
Office.initialize = () => {
    Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(
        Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged,
        () => {
            Excel.run(ctx => {
                const range = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
                range.load('address');
                return ctx.sync().then(() => {
                    const str = range.address;
                    if (str) {
                        const arr = str.split('!');
                        if (arr[1] !== '1:1048576') {
                            const cellNumber = arr[1];
                            ExcelValue.cellValue = cellNumber;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            Excel.run(context => {
                const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
                sheet.load('name');
                return context.sync().then(() => {
                    ExcelValue.sheetName = sheet.name;
                    setSheet(ExcelValue);
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error.debugInfo);
            });
        },
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `Office.onReady()`, as the `Office.initialize()` event fires at the end of the internal process in which Office.js initializes itself. And it fires immediately after the internal process ends. If the code in which you assign a handler to the event executes too long after the event fires, then your handler doesn't run.

So we recommend that you use `Office.onReady()` instead of `Office.initialize()`. Although `Office.initialize()` is still supported, `Office.onReady()` provides more flexibility.

The document can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in

Comment: getting this error sometime: Add-in Error: Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in.

Comment: I have tried your code, it doesn't repro this issue in my side, could you please share the script lab gist? here is the instruction how to share the gist https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab

Comment: I am using this code inside render function in React. is this correct place to define it??

Comment: I have used my code inside the componentDidMount and constructor as well. Now it is running fine in office.com but not running in office365 excel 2016 version. Can you please suggest..................

Comment: may i know your excel desktop version?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve by initializing the Office at the starting of the page and calling a function as shown below.

```
Office.initialize = function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        sheetPropertiesChanged();
     });
   };
   async function sheetPropertiesChanged() {    
    var rangeAddress;

    await Excel.run(async context => {
        const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        // Read the range address
        range.load("address");
        await context.sync();
        console.log(range.address);
        rangeAddress=range.address;
    }); 
}
```